# Alternating Elements

Tags: python-3.x

I've a list in Py3 below:

```
List1 = ['Harry','Potter']
```

I want to interchange the characters by position for every iteration.

For example if my number of iterations is 5,I want my output to be like this,

```
Harry Potter 

Potter Harry

Harry Potter

Potter Harry
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issue did you encounter with your first attempts?

Comment: Can you provide a simple output for 3 elements please? :)

Comment: lis1= ['Harry','Potter']
for words in lis1:
    print(lis[0],lis[1])

Comment: i only wanted for 2 elements.It was asked in an interview @ BlueSheepToken

Comment: perhaps incrementing and decrementing the indices in every iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to reorder your data ... you can simply print it one way or the other:

```
l = ['Harry', 'Potter']
reverse_it = False

for _ in range(10):  
    if reverse_it:
        print( *l[::-1] )
    else:
        print( *l )
    reverse_it ^= True # XOR with True flips the bool each time
                       # you can use 'reverse_it = not reverse_it' as well
```